# Bootstrap AngularJS make tabs active

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I know this has been asked a lot but it does not work for me. I simply want to make a tab appear active when it has been clicked. Heres what i already got:

```js
app.config(['$routeProvider', function( $routeProvider){
  $routeProvider.
  when('/maschinen', {
   templateUrl: 'maschinen.xhtml',
   controller: 'mainController',
                        activetab: 'maschinen'
  }).
                when('/personen', {
   templateUrl: 'personen.xhtml',
   controller: 'mainController',
                        activetab: 'personen'                        
  }).
                when('/qualifikation', {
                templateUrl: 'qualifikationen.xhtml',
                controller: 'mainController',
                activetab: 'qualifikation'
  });
  }]);
```

```html
<ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
    <li ng-class="{active: $route.current.activetab == 'index'}" data toggle="tab"><a ng-click="go('/index')">Home</a></li>
    <li ng-class="{active: $route.current.activetab == 'maschinen'}" data-toggle="tab"><a ng-click="go('/maschinen')">Maschinen/Tätigkeiten</a></li>
    <li ng-class="{active: $route.current.activetab == 'personen'}" data-toggle="tab"><a ng-click="go('/personen')">Personen</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: I can't see tabs in your snippet results. Only `<ul><li>`

Comment: in the html you have to scroll right, it should all be there @IsraGab

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In html:

```
<a ng-click="go('/index')>...</a>
```

In controller:

```
$scope.go = function(url)
{
    $location.path(url);
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks, this is nice and makes for less html code, but it doesnt answer my question.